# On second click; jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="example">
 Test
</div>

$('.example').click(function(){
 $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

When the code above get's clicked, it will apply the `.css`. Now what I need is for another bit of code (let's say `$(this).css('color','blue');`) to be applied, replacing the previous code when `.example` gets clicked a second time.

I've searched for this and askers seem to only need `.show`/`.hide` events which can be substituted with `.toggle`, which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: Are you wanting to just (for instance) switch between blue and red? because you can just do an `if` statement testing what the colour is and then applying the change from this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you may have many instances of class `example`, simply maintaining a state using a single variable is not feasible, what you can do is to maintain the state of each instance of `example` within itself:

Define two css classes

```
.example { background:blue }
.example.red { background:red }
```

Then your click method:

```
$('.example').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

If you prefer not to define new css classes, you can use `data()`, to make sure that the state is exclusive within each `.example`, this is useful if you have many instances of `.example`

```
$('.example').click(function() {
    var color = $(this).data('color');
    if(color != 'blue') {
       $(this).css('color', 'blue');
       $(this).data('color', 'blue');
    } else {
       $(this).css('color', 'red');
       $(this).data('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work to toggle between 2 colours (or styles).

```
$('.example').click(function(){  

     if($(this).css('color') == "red")
     {
        $(this).css('color','blue');
     }
     else
     {
        $(this).css('color','red');
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, if i'm only toggling between two options i find this a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="example">
 Test
</div>
```

just maintain a bool and you are done..

```
var isRed=false;
$('.example').click(function(){
 if(isRed)
 {
 $(this).css('color','blue');
 isRed=false;
 }
 else
 {
 $(this).css('color','red');
 isRed=true;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addClass and removeClass

```
.blueColor
{
background-color: blue;
}

.redColor
{
background-color: red;
}
```

And use in your javascript the addClass and removeClass functions:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".example").keypress(function() {
    if($(".example").val().length > 0)
    {
        $(".example").addClass("redColor");
    }
    else {
       if($(".example").val().length == 0) 
    {
    $(".example").addClass("blueColor");
    $(".example").removeClass("redColor");
    }
    }

    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something more generic about click event exactly so I'd suggest you to use `data` method to leave the flags

```
$('.example').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).data("custom-even")) {
        // odd execution        
        $(this).data("custom-even", true)
    } else {
        // even execution
        $(this).data("custom-even", false)
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.example').click(function(){
   var theExample = $(this);
   if(theExample.hasClass("clicked")){
      theExample.css('color','blue').removeClass("clicked");
   }else{
      theExample.css('color','red').addClass("clicked");
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SnDgh/

Answer (score 0):

Hiya Try this with `toggle` :)) http://jsfiddle.net/FVXAZ/

SO you can use toggle with your css and every second click will have the vice-a-versa affect. :)

**Code**

```
  $(function() {
   $('.example').toggle(function() {
    $(this).css('color','red');
   }, function() {
    $(this).css('color','blue');
   });
  });
```

Have a nice man man, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.example').click(function(){
      if($('.example').data('isAlreadyClicked')=='true')
      {
             $(this).css('color','blue');
             $('.example').data('isAlreadyClicked','false')
      } 
      else
      {
            $(this).css('color','red');
            $('.example').data('isAlreadyClicked','true') 
      }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **one** method to handle one-time event binding is a good choice, however this solution will stop all events binded **after** this code, it may cause inconsistency.

```
$('.example')
  .one('click', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediagePropagation();
  })
  .on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('color', blue');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot of answers all defining a single solution.

Basically, there are two ways that you should use. The other ways mentionned are either unperformant or unsemantic (using `data` for this kind of solution is overkill). Here are the two ways you may use:

```
// Toggle a class 'red' defined in your stylesheet
$('.example').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red')
})

// Toggle the color with an "if" check
$('.example').on('click', function() {
    if (this.style.color === 'red') { // using jQuery is not required
        this.style.color === 'blue'
    }
    else {
        this.style.color === 'red'
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
$('#id').toggle(function() {

  $('.css').css('color','red');}

,function() {           /////////the second click

   $('.css').css('color','blue');}
);
```